# Ubuntu/Docker stops routing UDP traffic for pihole

Tags: ubuntu, docker, pihole

I recently setup a pihole container on Ubuntu Server 22.04 via a `docker-compose.yml` file with `network_mode: 'host'` so that the traffic can be correctly routed to the UDP services running inside the container. This works for periods of time between 5 minutes and some days, but then the other local network hosts become unable to resolve DNS. It only seems to affect UDP traffic, pihole's HTTP-based web administration interface is still accessible and continues to refresh.

```bash
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

```
# More info at https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/ and https://docs.pi-hole.net/
version: "3"
services:
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    environment:
      BLOCKING_ENABLED: 'true'
      INSTALL_WEB_INTERFACE: 'true'
      PIHOLE_DNS_: '61.9.211.1;61.9.211.33'
      INTERFACE: 'enp2s0f0'
      QUERY_LOGGING: 'true'
      TZ: 'Australia/Brisbane'
      WEBPASSWORD: 'NoARealPassword'
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    # # For DHCP it is recommended to remove these ports and instead add: network_mode: "host"
    # ports:
    #   - "53:53/tcp"
    #   - "53:53/udp"
    #   - "67:67/udp" # Only required if you are using Pi-hole as your DHCP server
    #   - "80:80/tcp"
    network_mode: 'host'
    cap_add:
      # Required if you are using Pi-hole as your DHCP server.
      # REF: https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole#note-on-capabilities
      - NET_ADMIN
    # Causes the container to start after reboot - unless it was manually stopped.
    # REF: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - './etc-pihole:/etc/pihole'
      - './etc-dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d'
```

On a different local network host I am monitoring DNS lookups with:

```bash
while ( sleep 10s ); do
    date
    dig +short +retry=0 +time=1 @192.168.47.3 superuser.com
done
```

When DNS lookups fail I see the output:

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I am able to SSH into the Docker host perform DNS lookups from there, though:

```bash
$ dig +short +retry=0 +time=1 @192.168.47.3 superuser.com
151.101.129.69
151.101.193.69
151.101.65.69
151.101.1.69
```

This indicates that the Docker container and its services are at least up and running and that Docker UDP networking is partially operational. Searching around I came across this Github ticket for a similar, but different, UDP issue:

- [Failed to receive UDP traffic after container restart #8795](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8795)

It did mention the `conntrack` tool, though, so I installed that with `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes conntrack` and can see UDP state being maintained, though you can usually see one or two UNREPLIED entries in the output:

```bash
$ sudo conntrack -L -p udp
udp      17 14 src=192.168.47.3 dst=61.9.211.33 sport=48654 dport=53 src=61.9.211.33 dst=192.168.47.3 sport=53 dport=48654 use=1
udp      17 14 src=192.168.47.31 dst=192.168.47.3 sport=56688 dport=53 src=192.168.47.3 dst=192.168.47.31 sport=53 dport=56688 use=1
udp      17 15 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=48488 dport=48488 [UNREPLIED] src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=48488 dport=48488 use=1
udp      17 15 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=53642 dport=53 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=53 dport=53642 use=1
udp      17 24 src=192.168.47.31 dst=192.168.47.3 sport=65131 dport=53 src=192.168.47.3 dst=192.168.47.31 sport=53 dport=65131 use=1
udp      17 4 src=192.168.47.31 dst=192.168.47.3 sport=60055 dport=53 src=192.168.47.3 dst=192.168.47.31 sport=53 dport=60055 use=1
conntrack v1.4.6 (conntrack-tools): 6 flow entries have been shown.
```

When the local network hosts stop resolving DNS you see that the container processes are still listening but basically all conntrack entries are UNREPLIED:

```bash
$ systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-06-03 00:52:22 UTC; 1h 1min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 897 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 15
     Memory: 97.0M
        CPU: 3.593s
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─897 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Jun 03 00:52:15 pihole systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Jun 03 00:52:17 pihole dockerd[897]: time="2023-06-03T00:52:17.390901292Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
Jun 03 00:52:18 pihole dockerd[897]: time="2023-06-03T00:52:18.176864074Z" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
Jun 03 00:52:18 pihole dockerd[897]: time="2023-06-03T00:52:18.431091140Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Jun 03 00:52:19 pihole dockerd[897]: time="2023-06-03T00:52:19.751389637Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Jun 03 00:52:21 pihole dockerd[897]: time="2023-06-03T00:52:21.378339153Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Jun 03 00:52:21 pihole dockerd[897]: time="2023-06-03T00:52:21.696188540Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=659604f graphdriver=overlay2 version=24.0.2
Jun 03 00:52:21 pihole dockerd[897]: time="2023-06-03T00:52:21.722458798Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Jun 03 00:52:22 pihole dockerd[897]: time="2023-06-03T00:52:22.047272241Z" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
Jun 03 00:52:22 pihole systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.

$ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1344/lighttpd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1360/pihole-FTL     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      860/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4711          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1360/pihole-FTL     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1344/lighttpd       
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      1360/pihole-FTL     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      860/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:4711                :::*                    LISTEN      1360/pihole-FTL     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           1360/pihole-FTL     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           1360/pihole-FTL     
udp        0      0 192.168.47.4:68         0.0.0.0:*                           743/systemd-network 
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                1360/pihole-FTL     

$ sudo conntrack -L -p udp
udp      17 17 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=54075 dport=53 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=53 dport=54075 use=1
udp      17 3 src=192.168.47.31 dst=192.168.47.3 sport=51427 dport=53 [UNREPLIED] src=192.168.47.3 dst=192.168.47.31 sport=53 dport=51427 use=1
udp      17 17 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=39832 dport=39832 [UNREPLIED] src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=39832 dport=39832 use=1
udp      17 14 src=192.168.47.31 dst=192.168.47.3 sport=62519 dport=53 [UNREPLIED] src=192.168.47.3 dst=192.168.47.31 sport=53 dport=62519 use=1
udp      17 16 src=192.168.47.31 dst=192.168.47.3 sport=44415 dport=53 [UNREPLIED] src=192.168.47.3 dst=192.168.47.31 sport=53 dport=44415 use=1
udp      17 16 src=192.168.47.31 dst=192.168.47.3 sport=35812 dport=53 [UNREPLIED] src=192.168.47.3 dst=192.168.47.31 sport=53 dport=35812 use=1
udp      17 25 src=192.168.47.31 dst=192.168.47.3 sport=58360 dport=53 [UNREPLIED] src=192.168.47.3 dst=192.168.47.31 sport=53 dport=58360 use=1
udp      17 16 src=192.168.47.31 dst=192.168.47.3 sport=2478 dport=53 [UNREPLIED] src=192.168.47.3 dst=192.168.47.31 sport=53 dport=2478 use=1
udp      17 16 src=192.168.47.31 dst=192.168.47.3 sport=59483 dport=53 [UNREPLIED] src=192.168.47.3 dst=192.168.47.31 sport=53 dport=59483 use=1
udp      17 24 src=192.168.47.31 dst=192.168.47.3 sport=55490 dport=53 [UNREPLIED] src=192.168.47.3 dst=192.168.47.31 sport=53 dport=55490 use=1
conntrack v1.4.6 (conntrack-tools): 10 flow entries have been shown.
```

Restarting the pihole container doesn't seem to help, nor does restarting the Docker service, all that seems to work is rebooting the entire Docker host:

```bash
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND      CREATED       STATUS                    PORTS     NAMES
6a601dafd862   pihole/pihole:latest   "/s6-init"   11 days ago   Up 30 minutes (healthy)             pihole

$ docker container restart 6a601dafd862
6a601dafd862

# time passes, no improvement, so...
$ sudo systemctl restart docker.service

# time passes, no improvement, so...
$ sudo reboot
```

How can I further diagnose this problem? How can I prevent the issue in the first place?

(Aside from a monitoring host forcing a reboot of the Docker host over SSH. Which I'm considering. Or a reboot from an an hourly corontab.)